# Nothing happens after I sign in to Flutter app with Google Sign In

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play, google-signin

I have an app, at the start of the app you have to sign in with Google, then you can access the app and all that, but when I click on `Sign In With Google` nothing happens, the screen doesn't change or anything.

BUT when I run the app on an emulator it works fine and when I run `flutter run --release` on my actual phone it works fine. The problem only occurred when I put the app on the Google Play Store.

It won't help but here is the code for signing in anyway:

```
Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(), //loading icon
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return NavBar(); //returns the app
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                child: Text('Something has gone Wrong'),
              );
            } else {
              return logInPage(context); //log in page (button to log in)
            }
          },
        ),
      );
```

What I have tried: I made a new flutter project (`flutter create`) and copies the code over, I created a new Android emulator and I ran `flutter run --release` on my actual phone and I can't recreate the problem, does anyone know what to do?

Comment: i'm not sure what the problem is, but it does not sound like a code related problem, you could check if your google sign in is properly configured for android and ios platforms, including any permissions that might be needed in the manifest or info.plist files.

Comment: yeah i can't figure out what the problem is, everything is added and everything is there, like i said i can sign in without a problem but when i added it to the play store then it doesn't work, maybe it's not even a sign in problem, maybe its a state problem or a rendering problem, either way i think im just going to have to re-submit the app again